# Is there a way to resolve this ambiguity without using predicates?

Tags: antlr4

Grammar:

```
grammar Test;

file: (procDef | statement)* EOF;

procDef: 'procedure' ID NL statement+ ;

statement: 'statement'? NL;

WS: (' ' | '\t') -> skip;

NL: ('\r\n' | '\r' | '\n');

ID: [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
```

Test data:

```
statement

procedure Proc1
    statement
    statement
```

The parser does what I want (i.e. statement+ is greedy), but it reports an ambiguity because it doesn't know whether the last statement belongs to procDef or file (as I understand it).
As predicates are language dependent I'd prefer not to use one.
The procedure is supposed to end when a statement that can't belong to it, such as 'procedure', occurs.
I also would prefer to have the statements bound to the procedure to avoid having to rearrange the structure later.

### Edit

It seems I should expand my test data a bit (but I will leave the original as it is small and shows the ambiguity I want to solve).
I want to be able to handle situations like this:

```
statement

procedure Proc1
    statement
    statement

procedure Proc2
    statement
    statement

procedure Proc2a
    statement
    statement

global
statement

procedure Proc3
    statement
    statement
```

(The indentation is **not** significant.) I can do it without predicates with something like

```
file: (
        commonStatement
        | globalStatement
    )* EOF;

procDef: 'procedure' ID NL commonStatement+ ;

commonStatement: 'statement'? NL;

globalStatement: 'global' NL | procDef (globalStatement | EOF);
```

but then the tree becomes deeper with each consecutive procDef, and that feels very undesirable.
Then a solution with predicates is actually preferable.

```
@parser::members { boolean inProc; }

file: (
        {!inProc}? commonStatement
        | globalStatement
    )* EOF;

procDef: 'procedure' ID {inProc = true;} NL commonStatement+ ;

commonStatement: 'statement'? NL;

globalStatement: ('global' NL {inProc = false;} | procDef) ;
```

The situation is actually worse than this, as globally acessible commonStatements can occur without an intervening globalStatement (accessible through gotos), but there is no way a parser can distinguish between that and statements belonging to the procedure, so my plan was to just discourage such use (and I don't think it's common). In fact, it is perfectly legal to jump **into** procedure code as well ...
It may turn out that in the end I will have to examine runtime paths anyway (scope is very much determined at runtime), and the grammar might end up something like

```
file: (
        commonStatement
        | globalStatement
        | procDef 
    )* EOF;

procDef: 'procedure' ID NL procStatement*;

commonStatement: 'statement'? NL;

procStatement: 'proc' NL;

globalStatement: 'global' NL;
```

We will see ...

Answer (score 0):

By your criteria, it is impossible for a statement to follow a procDef. You are well within your rights to design a language that way, but I hope you have an answer ready for the FAQ "How do I write a statement which comes after a procedure definition."

Writing the grammar is the easy part:

```
file: statement* procDef* EOF;
```

Comment: Sorry, not that simple - there are other statements that are not allowed inside a procedure. And it is not my design, just creating a parser that can catch bugs other than at runtime  ...

Comment: @mabe: you can extend the model in the answer: `file: statement* (procDef|otherNonContainable|...)* EOF`. If that still doesn't match your needs, you'll have to make your question more explicit.